# ant classes finding eachother

Tags: java, apache, class, ant

im building an ant script to build an entire workspace and theres a lot in the workspace.
I know how to put jars on a classpath but I have some classes that need to see eachother, however some of these classes are generated using another ant script. What is the correct way of pointing to those classes once they're generated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Apache Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) - dependency management